# Overlapping multi-column indices

Tags: mysql, innodb

Consider a table like so (contrived example; I am trying to make it vaguely relatable):

```sql
CREATE TABLE `roles` (
  `host` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `port` smallint(6) NOT NULL,
  `user_id` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `role` varchar(50) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB
```

Typical data:

```sql
INSERT INTO TABLE `roles`
(host, port, user_id, role)
VALUES
('localhost', 8080, 'root', 'admin'),
('localhost', 8080, 'guest', 'readonly');
```

I know that the data is unique and non-null on:
`(host, port, user_id)`
I intend to use that multi-column index as my primary key.

But I would *also* like the covering index optimization for my SELECTs, which select all columns. To that end, I am considering adding also a wider multi-column index on:
`(host, port, user_id, role)`

So here's the question… if I create two indices, `(a,b,c)` and `(a,b,c,d)`: is MySQL/InnoDB smart enough to implement that as a single index under-the-hood?
Or will it create & maintain both indices, wasting space and time — and fail to notice that `(a,b,c,d)` is a superset of `(a,b,c)`?

I am tempted to avoid the problem and just make the primary key `(a,b,c,d)`, so that there's only one index. But that seems like a sub-optimal primary key (it considers more columns than necessary to guarantee uniqueness).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(a,b,c) may be used in preference (by the Optimizer) over (a,b,c,d) because the index is smaller.

Having both is a waste of disk space and leads to wasting room in cache when parts of both indexes are cached.  And this can lead to slower queries.

Instead of having both, keep the longer one.  It will handle both situations.

If `d` is a "big" column, then the index with it will be "big".  In this case, (a,b,c) may be the preferred one to keep.

On the other hand, (a,b,c) and (b,c,a) handle *different* queries, so you *may* need both.

[*Cookbook on building indexes*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql)

Answer (score 0):

If you create tow index So  (a,b,c) and (a,b,c,d) the query optimizer  can't choose the better  .. in this case you should explicitally assingn the index to use addin using clause to you join ..

but if you really need  you shoul consider the creation of not overlapping columns indexes eg:

```
 (a,b,c)
```

and

```
(d,c,b,a)
```

od other combinatio not starting with the same sequence

in this case the indexes  are choosed  by the grade of matching respect the query column

anyway you can find useful info here https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql-indexes.html

Comment: Why do you say that the query optimizer cannot choose the better of `(a,b,c)` vs `(a,b,c,d)`? Are you speaking with conditional clause? Regardless: my understanding is that if `(a,b,c,d)` is deemed more selective: optimizer will prefer it. Else if both indices are equally selective: optimizer will choose either (doesn't matter, unless I know better than the optimizer). But my question is about how much _space_ will be taken if both indices exist, and the cost of maintaining two indices with a huge overlap in purview.

Comment: The query optimizer  check for match between where column and index column  .. and once the index id get is used  also for select column ..  so in some case the query optimizer cannot choose the better for both where and select condition